# Does Python garbage collect when Heroku warns about memory quota vastly exceeded (R15)?

Tags: python, django, heroku, garbage-collection, celery

I have a background task running under Celery on Heroku, that is getting "Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)" frequently and "Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)" occasionally. I am loading a lot of stuff from the database (via Django on Postgres), but it should be loading up a big object, processing it, then disposing of the reference and loading up the next big object.

My question is, does the garbage collector know to run before hitting Heroku's memory limit? Should I manually run the gc?

Another thing is that my task sometimes fails, and then Celery automatically retries it, and it succeeds. It should be deterministic. I wonder if something is hanging around in memory after the task is done, and still takes up space when the next task starts. Restarting the worker process clears the memory and lets it succeed. Maybe Django or the DB has some caches that are not cleared?

I'm using standard-2x size. I could go to performance-m or performance-l, but trying to avoid that as it would cost more money.

Comment: I doubt that the python process knows about the memory quota, so I'd guess that it doesn't run the garbage collector. Either way, manual garbage collection is only useful in a select few number of edge-cases where a lot of memory can be freed up, but the thresholds for automatic collection aren't hit. It's more likely that you're simply using a lot of memory, in which case garbage collection can't clean up anything.

Comment: Can you paste your worker code that is fetching objects? There is likely a problem here, maybe you are not using a generator or loading things too eagerly. The memory error Heroku gives means you'll start using swap memory (on disk), which is very slow. Eventually, if you reach 1.5x your memory as swap, Heroku will restart your process and celery will re-try any jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that I'm not using `.iterator()` to iterate over the main queryset. Even though I'm freeing the data structures I'm creating after each iteration, the actual query results are all cached.

Unfortunately, I can't use `.iterator()`, because I use `prefetch_related` extensively.

I need some kind of hybrid method. I think it will involve processing the top-level queryset in batches. It won't completely have the advantage of a finite number of queries that `prefetch_related` has, but it will be better than one query per model object.

Comment: do you remember how you fixed this? I'm also getting this problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't remember. If you have the same problem, upvote the question, if not the answer.